# What's the appropriate way to access an enum from Swift Decodables?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, quicktype

I have a really weird case where I took JSON and thought I would be able to substring all the way to the data I want to access, however, it's not working as expected.

Using QuickType, I was able to convert this JSON: https://kidsuper.fodalabs.com/wp-json/wp/v2/art

To the below.

When trying to access, it seems like I should be able to do `.acf.gallery.id` however once I get to `acf.gallery`, it says `.id` does not exist. This is strange but here's what it returns when I try

```
let temp = imageArray[indexPath.row].acf.gallery.id
Value of type 'GalleryUnion?' has no member 'id'
```

Just for fun I tried this one and had no luck as well:

```
let temp = imageArray[indexPath.row].acf.GalleryUnion.galleryElementArray
    Error
```

: Value of type 'Acf' has no member 'GalleryUnion'

The return when I print `.acf.gallery` starts like this:

> ```
> Acf(company: "Season #3", 
>      gallery: Optional(weddingszn.GalleryUnion.galleryElementArray([weddingszn.GalleryElement(
>          id: 135, galleryID: 135, title: "1-791x1024", 
>          filename: "1-791x1024.jpg", url: "https://kidsuper.fodalabs.com/wp-content/up
> ```

Full code is below for what I'm trying to parse. Any ideas?

```
struct Acf: Codable {
    let company: String
    let gallery: GalleryUnion?
    let tagline: String
    let featuredImg: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case company, gallery, tagline
        case featuredImg = "featured_img"
    }
}

enum GalleryUnion: Codable {
    case bool(Bool)
    case galleryElementArray([GalleryElement])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            self = .bool(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode([GalleryElement].self) {
            self = .galleryElementArray(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(GalleryUnion.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for GalleryUnion"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .bool(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .galleryElementArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

struct GalleryElement: Codable {
    let id, galleryID: Int
    let title, filename: String
    let url: String
    let alt, author, description, caption: String
    let name, date, modified: String
    let mimeType: MIMEType
    let type: TypeEnum
    let icon: String
    let width, height: Int
    let sizes: Sizes

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case galleryID = "id"
        case title, filename, url, alt, author, description, caption, name, date, modified
        case mimeType = "mime_type"
        case type, icon, width, height, sizes
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `acf.GalleryUnion` be `acf. gallery`?

Comment: Yes, I tried them both, same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `GalleryUnion` can one of two things.  It can either both `.bool(_)` or `galleryElementArray(_)`.  When you want access the actual underlying value, you need to determine which state it's in.

To do this in Swift, you can use a `switch` statement.  You can then use it to gain access to the internally contained values.  Maybe something similar to:

```
if let gallery = acf.gallery {
    switch gallery {
    case .galleryElementArray(let values):
        values.forEach {
            print($0.id)
        }
    case .bool(_):
        break
    }
}
```

You might like to have a read of [Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html), look for the "Associated Values" sections

Answer (score 2):

You have to use if case, guard case or switch case to unpack the enum before you drill down into the array.

```
if case .galleryElementArray(let x) = imageArray[indexPath.row].acf.gallery {
    print(x.first!.id)
}
```

Comment: Champion! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

> however once I get to acf.gallery, it says .id does not exist. This is strange

No it isn't. According to your code, `.gallery` should be a GalleryUnion. Well, a GalleryUnion has no `.id`. It has no properties at all. A GalleryElement has an `.id`, but a GalleryUnion is not a GalleryElement. So I don't see where your surprise comes from; there is no surprise here.

A GalleryUnion has *cases*. You need to check which case this is. If it's `. galleryElementArray` you need to extract the associated value. Even then you won't have any `.id`, because what you will now have is still not a GalleryElement; it's an *array* of GalleryElements.

You could make this a lot easier on yourself by defining GalleryUnion with an extra calculated property that fetches the associated value for you:

```
enum GalleryUnion : Codable {
    case bool(Bool)
    case galleryElementArray([GalleryElement])
    var galleryElements : [GalleryElement]? {
        switch self {
        case .bool : return nil
        case let .galleryElementArray(arr): return arr
        }
    }
    // ... and so on
}
```

That would allow you, at least, to say:

```
act.gallery.galleryElements?.map {$0.id}
```

...or whatever it is you have in mind.

Comment: Showed how to drill down and extract the associated value _inline_, in a single line, more like the code you were originally trying to use.